# Unchecked Generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm having a little trouble with unchecked generics, maybe my design is a little off, but I'd appreciate some feedback. Given my design, each activity takes only a single specific request argument, I wish to intercept this at a higher layer agnostic to the request type (as shown in the code below).

```
public class DoSomethingActivity extends AbstractDoSomethingActivity implements SomeValidationInterface<DoSomethingRequest> {
    public DoSomethingResponse doSomething(DoSomethingRequest request) {
        // Business logic...
    }

    @Override
    public String getSomeValidationParam(DoSomethingRequest request) {
        return request.getSomeParam();
    }
}


public interface SomeValidationInterface<T extends UpdateRequest> {
    String getSomeValidationParam(T request);
}


public class SomeInterceptor implements InvocationInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object intercept(final Invoker invoker, final Object target, final Object... params) {
        if(params != null && params.length > 0 && params[0] instanceof UpdateRequest && target instanceof SomeValidationInterface) {
            final String someValidationParam = ((SomeValidationInterface) target).getSomeValidationParam((UpdateRequest) params[0]);
            validate(someValidationParam);
        }

        invoker.invoke(target, params);
    }

    public void validate(String someValidationParam) throws Exception {
        if (someValidationParam.equals("fail") {
            throw new Exception("Validation Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

The casting that I have to do to call getSomeValidationParam() from within my interceptor feels quite dirty, and generates compiler warnings about unchecked generics (though in my case, this shouldn't ever cause a run time issue). How can I better leverage generics to structure my code more pragmatically? Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the parameter types of `InvocationInterceptor#intercept`?

Comment: Nope, this is controlled by the request framework that I am using.

Comment: Then there's no way to prevent the explicit cast, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the warnings you can annotate the method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. In cases like that dirty tricks are a necessary evil.